# How to separate multi values from multiple pick list in salesforce

Tags: trigger

How to separate multi values received from multi pick list

Comment: Multi select picklist values are stored semi colon seperated in database. So you can split them by semi colon ";" to get seperated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using split string method by semicolon you can seprate values.

```
String[] picklistValues = **MultiselectPicklistAPIname**.split(';');
```

Comment: After checking for null first, though.

Comment: yes correct...  +1